Approximating mixing Bernoulli trials with Poisson random variables.
Consider a sequence of Bernoulli random variables $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)=p_i$ and assume that $p=\sum_{n\geq 1}p_i<\infty$. If the sequence is $\beta$-mixing, then are there bounds available for the probabilities
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\geq x\right)
\end{equation}
granted $\sum_{n\geq 0}\beta_n<\infty$?
I know that in the independent case, one could approximate the probability by a Poisson random variable with intensity $p$ (c.f., this paper and the remark below), yet I can not seem to find a similar result in case of dependent, but mixing, Bernoulli trials, except for this paper, which gives bounds on the quantity $\mu(f)-\nu_p(f)$ where $f:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\to\mathbb{R}$, $\mu$ is the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and $\nu_p(f)=e^{-p}\sum_{n\geq 0}p^nf(n)/n!$, i.e., the expectation under a Poisson$(p)$ law.
Remark: For the independent case, if $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent Bernoulli random variables with probabilities $0<p_i<1$, then if we define $\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^np_i$ and $p=\max_ip_i$, then Lemma 2 in the paper Poisson Approximation for Expectations of Unbounded Functions of Independent Random Variables implies that
\begin{equation}
\sup_{i\leq n}\frac{\mathbb{P}(X=i)}{\mathbb{P}(Z=i)}\leq\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}
\end{equation}
for $X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and $Z$ a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$. In that case, I suppose one can conclude that
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(X>x)\leq\frac{1}{(1-p)^2}\mathbb{P}(Z>x)
\end{equation}
for any $x\geq 0$, after which we can use tail estimates for Poisson random variables to bound the probability above, for example using concentration inequalities like Chernoff's bound.

What do you mean by $\beta$-mixing?

@温泽海 crudely speaking it means that the dependence between $X_n$ and $X_{n+k}$ dies out for every $n$ as $k\to\infty$. Here, $\beta$-mixing is simply one specific instance of a measure of dependence. A good explanation may be found on the wikipedia page.

Which bound (upper/lower) do you get in the independent case?

@DavideGiraudo, I added a remark on the independent case, I hope that helps.
